# Can't comment JavaScript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2008, a JavaScript function, I comment the line，. It's a usercontrol, and I get it in JavaScript. I want to comment the line, but it didn't work (
whether I add `//` or `/* */`, it doesn't work).

```
var user = document.getElementById('<%=UCSeletUser.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to ask here. Could you possibly rephrase the question?

Comment: Are you asking how do you comment out the line of JavaScript code.  But the problem is that the .NET code UCSeletUser.ClientID  is still being called.

Comment: yes , i commented the line,but it also said can't find control UCSeletUser,so weird.why .NET  still call the code between <%  and  =%>  inside a commented javascript line? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your JavaScript comments are just text like anything else to the ASPX processor. Anything not inside of the script markers is treated as a string literal -- it doesn't know or care that it's a JavaScript comment. It goes through the page looking for script sections (<% %>) and doing whatever is inside them, regardless of the surrounding text. (Things work slightly differently for databinding code <%# %>, but that's not relevant to your question.)

If you don't want that script block to run, you need to either take it out, or comment it out with server-side comments:

```
C#:    //var user = document.getElementById('<%//=UCSeletUser.ClientID %>');
VB:    //var user = document.getElementById('<%'=UCSeletUser.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: thank you! it is what i feel weird! microsoft should do sth advanced here maybe.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple script sections and you don't want to comment out each one where they may be related, you can use a script section to comment out all of it:

```
<%--
    var user = document.getElementById('<%=UCSeletUser.ClientID %>');
    var someOtherVal = document.getElementById('<%=someOtherVal.ClientID %>');
    var anotherVal = document.getElementById('<%=anotherVal.ClientID %>');
--%>
```

Of course, you can highlight multiple lines and use the Visual Studio command ctrl-K, ctrl-C to comment the lines out.  Use ctrl-K, ctrl-U to uncomment.